# I want to create an ActiveAdmin batch action that asks for an additional input field (a number) when selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

So I have Active Admin set up and managing all the items on a site I work on. There's a batch action that can put the items on sale, but currently the person has no input in what percentage that sale is. I have the action set up in the backend to just put everything selected on 10% off. But what I want is for the user to be able to input how much off they want the batch to be. Is there a built in way, in the Active Admin DSL to do this? If not, what would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use batch  action forms. Link to manual https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/9-batch-actions.md#batch-action-forms

For more complex tasks https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_scoped_collection_actions can be helpful